# Secured Directory creation in Linux

Tags: linux

How to create a directory with such a permission using a normal user in linux. And that directory should not be deleted using root user also ???  Any chance of creating it, if yes pls help me to do that.

thanks
Vijay

Comment: It doesn't look like you've been looking around enough. I just tested making a *file* with permissions 400 (user-only read-only) and even though `owner` could read, not write it, as expected, `root` was able to write to it.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to create a folder which cannot be deleted by root. Just Impossible.

Root is the **SUPER** user.

Here's a trick with using `chattr`. But keep in mind every root can remove this attribute, too. So it's not really safe. See http://jesin.tk/make-undeletable-files-and-directories-linux/

Comment: The OP could use [chattr +i](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html) to make the deletion more difficult (on Ext3 or Ext4 filesystems), but root could always undo that.

Comment: Oh ya, that's true. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what language you are using, but you should look at the -m (--mode) option to [mkdir](http://man.cx/mkdir) if you're in a shell. Alternatively look at the [umask()](http://man.cx/umask%282%29) function which is exposed in many languages.

Timo is correct however, you cannot protect a directory from the root user.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that root can delete any file in the file system. One trick to get around this though is to create a file in a running process, open a file handle to it and then delete the file. Root cannot access the file then as it does not exist in the file system. However, Linux will retain the file for as long as any process has it open - you can still read from it and write to it. So essentially an invisible file that is safe from root.

A good example of this gotcha is when not so clued up sys admins delete apache log files as root to free up disk space. The files have been deleted from the file system but apache will continue writing to these now invisible files until someone reboots the server or restarts apache with 'service httpd restart'. Only then is the disk space recovered.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible on a standard hard disk. By definition, the root user has access to every aspect of the system that isn't blocked by hardware. You can try setting the permissions 000 on it with chmod, and deny deletion with chattr, as a stopgap. The root user can still change permissions and even access the drive directly, bypassing the filesystem.

Another thing to do is to stick the directory on a drive with a write lock and then set the write lock.

Comment: This is one of the interview question which is asked for me in a reputed MNC company i was speech less @ that time.

Comment: @Vijay So the answer is you can't with 100% certainty, without hardware write protection. Say that if asked again.